# Adding a game service in XNA 4.0 through vb.net

Tags: xna-4.0

I have seen a number of examples explaining how to add a game service in C#.  They usually look like the following:

```
this.Services.AddService(typeof(SpriteBatch), spriteBatch);
```

For the time being, I will be working on the vb.net side, and don't know enough C# to translate this.  the typeOf method seems to want a type and an object, and return a boolean value.  This doesn't seem like what I want.  Does anyone know enough of both C# and vb.net to translate or fill me in on what I'm missing?

Comment: in your "sub new" method of your Game class, inherits from Game. Have you checked what intelisense has to say about "Me.Services.AddService"? Sry i don't know VB, but i don't think it should be to hard translating C# to VB.net. and instead of typeof i think its GetType(SpriteBatch).

Comment: It was GetType.  I don't know why everything I've been reading seems wrong.  Thank you very much!